# How can I create and delete a database at the first and at the end of a Fact in XUnit testing?

Tags: c#, testing, integration-testing, xunit, xunit.net

In testing some services that connected to the database in integration tests I need to create a single database for a fact and after finish the fact I need to delete that database because in XUnit ,tests are parallel and this can effect to each other for example you wanna edit a user in database in a fact but before this fact there is an other fact has deleted that user and this make my test failed so I need to create a single database for each fact and after finish that fact I want to dispose that database

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different solutions to this issue. But they all boil down to removing the shared resource.

1. Remove parallelization for xUnit : You can do that by adding a a xunit.runner.json and add `parallelizeTestCollections` to that file as described in the [documentation](https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files#parallelizeTestCollections) and you can use [Respawn](https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn) along with that to restore the database to a checkpoint after each test. If you have a lot of tests, then this solution may be slow but can be faster than firing up a db each time. (this is not advisable, see @RubenBartelink answer below)
2. If there is no relation between the two users of each test then you can use a different Identifier for each user and make the test independent of each others.
3. If the test is not about integration with the db, than you can use an memory database.
4. And last, you can [use a docker image](https://wrapt.dev/blog/integration-tests-using-sql-server-db-in-docker) of the db, perhaps varying one of the connection parameters in order to make each test target an individual database or schema etc.

Comment: actually the answer is docker but the problem is our project don't use docker so I can't use it  .
But **Respawn** was practical  and I think that's what I'm looking for thank you

Comment: While some of the stuff you've suggested is helpful, there's also some outright bad advice. Completely neutering the parallelism is not necessary, or a good idea. Collection Fixtures are the way to restrain parallel access in a more targeted way

Comment: @RubenBartelink thanks for the addition.  I'll add it to the edit.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Collection Fixture](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context). This addresses your needs by:

1. only letting one test that needs the resource use it at a time
2. allowing you to do a single spin up/down per overall test run

Comment: Does the collection fixture by itself synchronize access to the fixture by multiple tests in the same collection?

Comment: I found it out, it should be usage of Collection fixture, alongside a custom Test collection for tests that should be run sequentially. Thanks Ruben.

Comment: Yes. Parallelism is never applied within a single Test Class (or across instances of a Theory etc). Think of a Collection fixture as merging the Test Classes from the point of view of controlling concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in a similar situation and made helper class for unit tests requiring database access which creates a new schema in the database for the test and removes it upon being `Dispose`d. You can add any tables or views you want to the schema.

I use it in the test fixture so that it only creates the schema once for each collection, but you could do it for each `Fact`, although you'll probably start to get performance issues if there are a large number of them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace UnitTestHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class supports creation of temporary schemas in an existing database to be
    /// able to use them in unit tests.<br/>
    /// The schemas are deleted on disposal of the object.
    /// </summary>
    public class DataBaseUnitTestHelper : IDisposable
    {
        private bool schemaCreated = false;
        private bool disposedValue;

        /// <summary>
        /// Public constructor requires naming the data source and database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataSource_">The data source, i.e. server name of the database server.</param>
        /// <param name="catalog_">The database name where the temporary schemas will be created.</param>
        public DataBaseUnitTestHelper(string dataSource_, string catalog_)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataSource_))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(dataSource)} is null or empty.", nameof(dataSource_));
            }
            this.dataSource = dataSource_;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(catalog_))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(catalog_)} is null or empty.", nameof(catalog_));
            }
            this.catalog = catalog_;
        }

        public string dataSource { get; private set; }
        public string catalog { get; private set; }
        public string schema { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Builds a connect string that can be used to connect to the database,
        /// for example in <see cref="SqlConnection.SqlConnection(string)"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public string connectString
        {
            get
            {
                if (disposedValue) throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.ToString());
                if (connectString_ == null)
                {
                    var csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                    csb.DataSource = dataSource;
                    csb.IntegratedSecurity = true;
                    csb.InitialCatalog = catalog;
                    connectString_ = csb.ConnectionString;
                }
                return connectString_;
            }
            private set
            {
                if (disposedValue) throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.ToString());
                connectString_ = value;
            }
        }

        private string connectString_ = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a (normally unopened) connection to the database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlConnection getConnection()
        {
            if (disposedValue) throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.ToString());
            return new SqlConnection(connectString);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new  uniquely named schema in the given database and returns its name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The name of the schema that was created.</returns>
        public string createNewTestSchema()
        {
            if (disposedValue) throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.ToString());

            if (schemaCreated)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Object can only be used to create one test schema.");
            }
            using (SqlConnection connection = getConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                string localSchema = "Test" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(0, 16);
                string sql = $"CREATE SCHEMA {localSchema};";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    int res = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    schema = localSchema;
                    schemaCreated = true;
                }
                return schema;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes the temporary database schema created by this object,  first clearing all its elements 
        /// </summary>
        private void deleteSchema()
        {
            if (disposedValue) throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.ToString());

            if (!schemaCreated) return;

            // Determine all the objects in the schema
            List<Tuple<string, string>> list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
            using (SqlConnection connection = getConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand selectTablesCmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    selectTablesCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] WHERE [TABLE_CATALOG] = @tableCatalog AND [TABLE_SCHEMA] = @tableSchema";
                    selectTablesCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tableCatalog", catalog);
                    selectTablesCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tableSchema", schema);
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = selectTablesCmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string tableName = reader["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                            string tableType = reader["TABLE_TYPE"].ToString();
                            list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(tableName, tableType));
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Delete all the objects in the Schema
                if (list.Count > 0)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand deleteTableCmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                    using (SqlCommand deleteViewCmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        foreach (Tuple<string, string> item in list)
                        {
                            switch (item.Item2)
                            {
                                case "BASE TABLE":
                                    deleteTableCmd.CommandText = $"DROP TABLE [{catalog}].[{schema}].[{item.Item1}]";
                                    deleteTableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    break;
                                case "VIEW":
                                    deleteViewCmd.CommandText = $"DROP VIEW [{catalog}].[{schema}].[{item.Item1}]";
                                    deleteViewCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    throw new InvalidDataException($"Found table type '{item.Item2}' in [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] for" +
                                        $" [{catalog}].[{schema}].[{item.Item1}], expected 'BASE TABLE' or 'VIEW'.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Delete the schema itself
                using (SqlCommand dropSchemaCmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    dropSchemaCmd.CommandText = $"DROP SCHEMA {schema}";
                    dropSchemaCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                schema = null;
                schemaCreated = false;
                return;
            }
        }


        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects)
                }

                // Free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override finalizer
                deleteSchema();

                disposedValue = true;
            }
        }

        ~DataBaseUnitTestHelper()
        {
            // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
            Dispose(disposing: false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
            Dispose(disposing: true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
        [Fact]
        public void testSchemaIsReallyCreated()
        {
            string schema;
            string connectString;

            using (DatabaseUnitTestHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseUnitTestHelper(defaultDataSource, defaultInitialCatalog))
            {
                connectString = dbhelper.connectString;
                schema = dbhelper.createNewTestSchema();

                bool schemaExists;
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT COUNT(*) from SYS.SCHEMAS WHERE name = @schema";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("schema", schema);
                    schemaExists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
                }

                Assert.True(schemaExists, $"Schema {schema} doesn't exist although method {nameof(dbhelper.createNewTestSchema)} was executed and this schema name was returned.");
            }
        }
```